# How can i select the integers inside my string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to ask the user for a basic operation such as "4*5+25-5.5/1" and then solve it, how do i split my string without without forgetting the opreatorsor how can i select my numbers and place them elsewhere?

ive tried spliting (with .split()) each operator leaving only the numbers. The problem arises when i want to actually solve the equation

```
operation = (4*5+25-5.5/1)
operation = operation.replace(*, " ")
operation = operation.replace(/, " ")
operation = operation.replace(+, " ")
operation = operation.replace(-, " ")
list of operation = operation.split(" ")
```

this creates a list with `[4, 5, 25, 5.5, 1]` but i can no longer use the operators since i deleted them.

Answer (score 3):

In addition of splitting the string into digits and operators as mentioned above, you can always use `eval` to evaluate the string without the need to split.

```
In [13]: eval("4*5+25-5.5/1")                                                   
Out[13]: 39.5
```